# specify geometry of a new gnuplot window in lxde

Tags: x11, window-manager, window, lxde, gnuplot

I have a script that runs a calculation and then plots the result using gnuplot script file. The problem is that I need to make more than one plot and I don't want windows to cover each other. 
I tried this:

```
time ./run nano.lua
killall gnuplot
gnuplot -geometry -100-100 -p -e 'load "pqpss.plt"'
gnuplot -p -e 'load "pqpsss.plt"'
```

turns out that the `-geometry` option doesn't do anything.
I'm tunning lxde with ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I don't want to use multiple plots within gnuplot because I can't easily resize them

Answer (score 1):

Seems this might be a known bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=599129

Workaround suggest explicitly adding `-display :0.0` (substituting your display as necessary):

```
$ gunuplot -geometry -100-100 -display :0.0 -p -e 'locat "pqpss.plt"'
```